# не включается gii в yii2

Tags: yii2, gii

gii я пользовался сотню раз, он у меня подключен и при надобности я раскомментирую строки, поработаю и комментирую для отключения. Но сейчас раскомментировав строки я получил

> The file or directory to be published does not exist:
>   /home/host_name/site.com/www/vendor/bower-asset/typeahead.js/dist

Этой папки действительно нет на сервере, проверил бекапы, в них тоже этой папки нет. Как оно работало раньше - не понимаю. Папки нет и не было. В дистрибутивах yii2 вообще папки  vendor нету.

Плиз, хелп.

Answer (score 0):

Какой-то треш. Погуглил и нашёл эту папку на сайте, который по неосторожности не закрыл её у себя http://www.colonspanishschool.com/vendor/bower-asset/typeahead.js/ Скачал, заработало!!!

У меня этой папки отродясь не было, я проверил все бекапы на локали и на хосте. Как оно работало - хз!

Comment: Если пользуешься композером, то эта директория всегда создается.